# How to get the (saved) settings of an add-in after the add-in is loaded?

Tags: javascript, office-js

After the task pane of my add-in has loaded, I want to get a setting I saved before ([as described here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings)).

I'm doing it here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mysetting").val(Office.context.Settings.get("mysetting"));
});
```

But - obviously - I get an error indicating:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

This error is IMO due to the fact that the document is ready before Office initialization is ready, right?

But, how do I check if Office is ready to be used?

What do I do wrong, or have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling this from `$(document).ready`. That only tells you that the DOM as loaded, it doesn't tell you that your add-in has been wired up to the Office Application.

Instead, you need to do this from within the [`Office.initialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/loading-the-dom-and-runtime-environment) method. This method gets fired after Office is ready for your add-in. You can add an additional check for `$(document).ready` within this method to ensure the DOM is also loaded:

```
Office.initialize = function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Your code here
  });
};
```

You also need to make sure you're settings collection is populated before attempting to access elements within the collection. This is done by calling `refreshAsync` before reading from the settings collection:

```
Office.initialize = function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Populate the settings collection
    Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(function(asyncResult) {
      // Read your setting
      let mySetting = Office.context.settings.get("mysetting");

      // Since this setting may not exist, check it before assigning
      if (mySetting) $("#myDomElement").val(mySetting);
    });
  });
};
```

Also, make sure you're calling [`saveAsyn`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.saveasync) after setting a value. Office won't automatically persist the settings, you need to explicitly tell it when to write those settings back to the document.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks a bunch for your help! 
I actually was using the Office.initialze method but avoided it to mention in my question to make it easier to read.
I also call the saveAsync to ensure the values persist - thx anyway for reminding ;)
Will see if/how the reshAsync works and will soon let you know.

Comment: Finally, it worked - although I had to test a lot!
BUT, there was a slight change needed to be done since I always received "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined".

Instead of (what you suggested)
'Office.context.Settings.get'
I had to use
'Office.context.document.settings.get'

Please take a look at the difference of the "S" vs. "s" for settings.
When using the big "S" the code failed all the time - but when using the small "s" it workd like a charme :))
Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: The only disadvantage is - the settings are saved only within the document (here: Excel file) and not globally in Office (here: Excel).
Am I seeing this right?
If so, I'll have to figure out, what the correct code is to save it not only within the document.

Comment: DOH! I'll check the documentation and make sure this was mine rather than a copy & paste typo. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You're correct, these settings are stored with the document. This allows these settings to remain _with_ the document, even if you've forwarded it to someone else. For global settings, it depends on what you're looking to store. Personal/User settings can be stored as cookies (they will get restored with your add-in) or you can store them remotely (Open Extensions via Microsoft Graph is great for this).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional information, @Marc!
Currently, I'll stay with the option to store the information with the document.
As soon as this works as I want to, I'll go the next step to use Microsoft Graph.
I always think: Do it step-by-step and make sure each step works perfectly ;)